# $D(p||q) \geq \frac12(2(p-q))^2,\,\,\,p\geq q$?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Suppose we have binary distributions $P,Q$ with probabilities $p\geq q$. Is it true that $D(p||q) \geq \frac12(2(p-q))^2$?

What I have so far is that $p\log\frac pq+(1-p)\log\frac{1-p}{1-q} \geq \log \min(\frac pq,\frac{1-p}{1-q}) = \log(\frac{1-p}{1-q})$ as $p\geq q$ implies $1-q \geq 1-p$, and that log is equal to $\log (1-p) - \log (1-q)$, but I don't think I can go on from there... any hints from here?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I've added my current working, just a bit frustrated with what seems like should be a simple problem, thanks.

Comment: A hint if you want a go at this without seeing the above answer: for a fixed $p$, define $f(\varepsilon) = D(p\|p+\varepsilon)$ in nats (i.e., with a natural logarithm in $D$). Show that $f$ is strongly convex in $\varepsilon$.

Comment: These are tremendously helpful! I'll give these a shot.

Comment: It's actually really clever to do that, thanks! As a follow up question, if I wanted to extend this to any two general distributions P and Q and prove $D(P||Q) \geq \frac12(||P-Q||_1)^2$, would if be sufficient to first create a set $X' = \{x; P(x) \geq Q(x)\}$, create a binary variable $Y$ taking 0 if $x\in X'$ and 1 otherwise, and then creating markov chains $X\rightarrow P\rightarrow P'$, $X\rightarrow P\rightarrow Q'$ to use the data processing inequality and say $D(P||Q) \geq D(P'||Q')$? Im doing this part to make sure i understand the concepts properly...

Comment: Indeed, that's perfectly correct, except that some of the notation is a bit off ($X \to P \to P'$ doesn't really make sense, one of those is a random variable, the others are laws that are not random, and I don't know what you mean then). The resulting bound is called Pinsker's inequality. (Oh, also, of course, $D(p\|q)$ is an abuse of notation, you should strictly speaking be writing something like $D(\mathrm{Bern}(p)\|\mathrm{Bern}(q)).$ This is sometimes also denoted $d(p\|q)$ or $d_2(p\|q)$. Just pointing it out since notation came up in my comment).